# Concmath drop-off in quality for equations

Tags: math-mode, fonts

[image: Concmath math symbol]

[image: Normal math symbol]

Is there a way to display equations in concrete font style without the drop-off in quality that the package concmath has? (the first picture is with concmath package, the second is without it.)

Comment: as far as I know the only type1 versions of concrete math generally available are not free and may be purchased from micropress see the uktug faq for a link http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-psfchoice.html (probably these days fontforge could make a reasonable scalable font from the metafont bitmaps)

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the resolution of the bitmap fonts:

```
\pdfpkresolution=2400
\pdfpkmode={supre}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{concmath}

\begin{document}

$\partial^{\mu}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a similar solution for XelateX? As far as I am aware your solution works for pdflatex.